# Can't run Tensorflow-federated on GPU

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I am trying to run my python code which uses `tensorflow-federated` on a GPU. To set up my environment, I use `venv`. First, I install `tensorflow-gpu`, and my python code then can recognize the GPU, I use `tf.test.gpu_device_name()`. However, as soon as I install `tensorflow-fedenerated`, my python stops seeing any GPU and starts using CPUs!! 
I am using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. I tried a plenty of combinations of different versions of the packages:

```
python = 3.6, 3.7
cuda = 10.0, 10.1
tensorflow-gpu = 1.13.1, 1.15, 2.1.0, 2.0.0-alpha0
tensorflow-fedenerated = 0.2.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say exactly what the problem is here, but I do have a suspicion.

TFF [declares TensorFlow 2.1 as a required package](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/tools/development/setup.py#L84); this may mean that your TF-gpu installation is being *removed* during the TFF installation setup.

Can you please try the following order:

- Open a fresh `venv`
- Install TFF
- Uninstall TF
- Install TF GPU 2.1.0

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can say that installing TFF does not remove tensorflow-gpu, because I can see it in my packages list.
However, I followed your tips, unfortunately, still the GPU is not recognized. Here are the relevant part of packages in the fresh ```venv```:
```tensorboard                   2.1.1
tensorflow-addons             0.8.3
tensorflow-estimator          2.1.0
tensorflow-federated          0.13.1
tensorflow-gpu                2.1.0
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.2.1
tensorflow-privacy            0.2.2```